# 2 definitions of multivariable calculus I'd like to know the name

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Here the 1st one:

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$  a subset of real numbers and $x() y():I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ two functions
Let us define $(x(t),y(t)):I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$
What's the name of this specific two variable function? My teacher didn't say it at all and started drawing some "graphs" about it without explaining their meaning, I just want to know what's the name of this type of function so I can start researching about them on my own to understand what it even means.

To give more context hoping it can help, I after that he started defining direction, directional derivatives and direction of maximum slope.

The 2th one:
Let
$X:[a,b]→A $ with $A⊂ \mathbb{R}^d $

$X(t)=(x_1(t),.....,x_d(t))$, and $f:A→\mathbb{R}$

$F(t)=f(X(t))$, how's this function F called?

Comment: I supposed you can search for "parametric curves".

Comment: While how's definite the function $F$ such that, $ X:[a,b]\rightarrow A$ with $A\subset \mathbb{R} $,$ X(t)=(x_1(t),.....,x_d(t))$, and $ f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $F(t)=f(X(t))$, how do you call such F?

Comment: If $A\subset \mathbb R$, then you couldn't have $d$ components. Please do not ask questions in comments.

Comment: @Aoi , if you could post that as an answer and explain the scope (that they don't just have to be 2d), this question would no longer appear unanswered.

Comment: I tried to modify with $\mathbb{R}^d$ , i can't ask in comments? So I'll add it to my question